# hostname in certificate didn't match

Tags: android, post, ssl, https, сертификат

Есть приложение на андроид, которое отправляет запросы к php скриптам на моем сайте, по https. Сертификат Let's Encrypt автоматически меняется каждые 3 месяца. Первые 3 месяца отработало все прекрасно. Сегодня сертификат на сайте заменился и приложение стало выдавать ошибку **hostname in certificate didn't match**

Протестировал сертификат на разных сайтах, везде пишут, что он валидный и соответствует домену. Кто нибудь сталкивался с таким? Что делать, куда писать уже не знаю.. сайт hiki-soft.ru Запрос посылаю через SyncHttpClient httpClient = new SyncHttpClient();

Comment: служба поддержки хостинга посоветовала стереть АААА запись в настройках домена и подождать пару часов, поглядим что будет

Comment: прошло 20 часов, пока не заработало ( есть у кого идеи, что можно еще попробовать?